# Javascript: Listening for multiple asynchronous Google Maps API v3 requests to finish

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous, listener

I am currently using a `setInterval` function to "listen" for a "ready" variable to be set, using multiple Google Geocoder callbacks.

I was wondering if there is a more "legit" or efficient way to do this, perhaps using a jQuery Deferred Object or .ajaxStop().

I just don't know how these work or if they are compatible with the Google Geocoder API and callback functions.

So currently I am setting the var, `geocodeReady` to `true` once all Geocoding is finished, then setting an interval function every 1000 ms to check whether `geocodeReady` is set to true yet.

Is there a more efficient/faster/concise way to do this?

Thank you!

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var addresses = [
    ['Bondi Beach Australia'],
    ['Coogee Beach Australia'],
    ['Cronulla Beach Australia'],
    ['Manly Beach Australia']
];

var n = addresses.length;
var geocodeReady = false;

for (i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    (function(address){

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addresses[i][0]}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                address.push(results[0].geometry.location.lb);
                address.push(results[0].geometry.location.mb);

            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }

            if (--n == 0) {
                geocodeReady = true;
            }                                   
        });

    })(addresses[i]);
}

var x = 0;

// set a timer to check whether our addresses have geocoded

function checkGeocode() {

    if(x === 10) {
        clearInterval(geocodeTimer);
    }

    if(geocodeReady == true) {
        clearInterval(geocodeTimer);

        for (i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(addresses[i][1], addresses[i][2]),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(addresses[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    }

    x++;
}

var geocodeTimer = setInterval(checkGeocode, 1000);

geocodeTimer;
```

Comment: You are using undocumented properties of the [google.maps.LatLng object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng), `address.push(results[0].geometry.location.lb); address.push(results[0].geometry.location.mb);` don't do that, use the documented .lat(), .lng() methods.

Comment: Not sure why you feel you need to save the coordinates in the array either.  The usual solution is to geocode the address, add the marker and the infowindow in the callback to the geocoder rather than saving them and adding the markers once all the geocoding is done as you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Using YUI (Yahoo User Interface).

```
YUI().use("parallel", function(Y){
var stack = new Y.Parallel();
for (i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    (function(address){

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addresses[i][0]}, stack.add(function(results, status) {
            //every callback function will get into the stack.
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                address.push(results[0].geometry.location.lb);
                address.push(results[0].geometry.location.mb);
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }

        }));

    })(addresses[i]);
}

//when all callbacks are done...
stack.done(function(){
     console.log("all geocoding are finished");
});    

});
```

For a complete documentation on Parallel module from YUI3 visit [user guide](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/parallel.html) or [library API](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Parallel.html). The documentation is small and easy to use. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is another approach than counting the requests(`YUI.Parallel` also does it).

I guess you want to execute something when all requests have been finished. So instead of checking the variable from the outside execute the desired function when `n==0` (the function to execute may be passed as argument when you want to be more dynamic)

```
for (var i = 0,n=addresses.length; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    (function(address,callback){
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address[0]}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                address.push(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                address.push(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " 
                       + status);
            }
            if (--n === 0) {            
                callback(addresses);
            }                                   
        });

    })(addresses[i],
       function(){console.dir(addresses);alert('geocoding finished');});
}
```